# Suppose that n=ab, where a ≥ b > 2 and gcd (a,b)=1. By working mod a and mod b, prove that there are at least 4 different solutions to x^2.=1 mod n.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've started by stating that if $x^2=1\mod n$, since $n=ab$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then $x^2=1\mod a$ and $x^2=1\mod b$.

Now, I know that for $a,b \gt 2$, there will always be at least two solutions for $x^2=1 \mod a$, which are $x=1$ and $x=a-1$. In the same logic, there will always be at least two solutions for $x^2=1 \mod b$, which are $x=1$ and $x=b-1$. Does this complete the proof, or if it doesn't am I close?

Comment: You've got two solutions mod a and two solutions mod b. You haven't yet got *any* solutions mod ab. So you definitely need another step.

Comment: I think you should move the problem from the title into the content.

Comment: Actually, you do not even got two solutions mod a because
$a^2\equiv 0 \not \equiv 1\pmod a!\,$ I guess you mean $x\equiv \pm 1$

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I understand now. So I did mean 1 or a-1.